# PIL - TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import argparse
import cv2
import os

image  = Image.open("C:/Users/NB/Desktop/Scan/Arti818.jpg")

#image = "C:/Users/NB/Desktop/Scan/Arti818.jpg"
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# check to see if we should apply thresholding to preprocess the
# image

gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,  cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# make a check to see if median blurring should be done to remove
# noise

# write the grayscale image to disk as a temporary file so we can
# apply OCR to it
filename = "{}.png".format(os.getpid())
cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)
# load the image as a PIL/Pillow image, apply OCR, and then delete
# the temporary file
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
os.remove(filename)
print(text)

# show the output images
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.imshow("Output", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is my code and I am getting following error:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

Answer (score 4):

[Read the docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open). It clearly says:

> #### `PIL`.`Image`.`open`(`fp, mode='r'`)
>
> Opens and identifies the given image file.
>   Returns: An `Image` object.

The object returned is of `Image` type, not a `numpy.ndarray`. If you want an array, convert `image` to one:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```