# Count total number of white pixels in an image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to count total number of white pixels in the following image:

[image]

But with my code, I get this error

> src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar.

This is my code:

```
img=cv2.imread(filename,1)
TP= width * height
white= TP - cv2.countNonZero(img[1])
print "Dimensions:", img.size, "Total pixels:", TP, "White", white
```

Comment: use `cv2.imread(filename, 3)` `3 for being bgr` and when passing to `countNonZero` make sure you only get one channel like `img[0]`

Comment: @pixelthread don't add information by comments. Improve your post instead!

Comment: Sorry i dont know how it went so wrong i edited i hope its okay now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PIL: TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238897/pil-typeerror-src-is-not-a-numpy-array-neither-a-scalar)

Comment: I would suggest that if you edit your OP, don't change your posted code (unless you included an error) but add the edited code after. Because now your error code above doesn't actually follow from the code below it, which will confuse others reading this question later.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Notice that `Image` is capitalized...in PIL, `Image` is a class. The actual image data is one of the many properties inside the class, and PIL does not use numpy arrays. Thus, your image is not a numpy array. If you want to convert to a numpy array, simply encase the image as an array:

```
img = np.array(img)
```

If you read the image with OpenCV, then it already comes as a numpy array.

```
img = cv2.imread(filename)
```

Also note that the ordering of channels is different in PIL than OpenCV. In PIL, images are read as RGB order, while in OpenCV, they are in BGR order. So if you read with PIL but display with OpenCV, you'll need to swap the channels before displaying.

---

Edit: also, check the [OpenCV docs for `countNonZero()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.countNonZero). This function only works on single channel arrays, so you'll need to either convert the image to grayscale, or decide how you want to count a zero. You can also just use numpy just by `np.sum(img == 0)` to count the number of zero values, or `np.sum(img > 0)` to count non-zero values. For a three channel array, this will count all the zeros in each channel independently. If you want to only include ones that are zero in all three colors, you can do a number of things---the simplest is probably to add all the channels together into one 2D array, and then do the same as above.

---

Edit2: also, your code right now is counting the number of *black* pixels, not white. `countNonZero()` will return the number of all pixels greater than 0. Then you subtract that off the total number of pixels...which will give you only the black pixels. If you just want to count the number of white pixels, `np.sum(img == 255)`.

---

Edit3: So with your image, this code works fine:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
n_white_pix = np.sum(img == 255)
print('Number of white pixels:', n_white_pix)
```

> Number of white pixels: 5

Note here that `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` is just equal to 0, but this is more explicit.

Comment: `img=cv2.imread(filename,3)
img = np.array(img)
TP= width * height
white= TP - cv2.countNonZero(img)
print "Dimensions:", img.size, "Total pixels:", TP, "White", white`

Comment: It still doesn't return total number of white pixels

Comment: If you're reading the image with OpenCV, it is already a numpy array, so you don't need to cast it again. Also you don't need to use 3 in `imread()`; any number > 0 will give a BGR image, but by default it reads as BGR anyways. Check the [docs for `cv2.countNonZero()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.countNonZero); it only works on single channel images.

Comment: No error but **white pixel and total pixel are same **

Comment: @pixelthread look at my second edit; you're not counting the white pixels. Post an example image and I can edit with showing a count of that image's white pixels.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519099/np-sum-not-returning-total-counts check this one

Answer (score 2):

I am using map data structure it will give you different pixels from an image and also their count. You can use any other data structure, you are comfortable with.

```
map<Vec3b, int> palette;
for (int y = 0; y<im.rows; y++) {

for (int x = 0; x<im.cols; x++)
    {
        Vec3b color = im.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y));
        if (palette.count(color) == 0)
        {
            palette[color] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            palette[color] = palette[color] + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One has to have a clear understanding of `cv2.countNonZero()` before using it.

- It can be used only with an image of single channel. In other words, an image with only two dimensions (width and height). When used with a 3-channel image you would face an assertion error: `(-215:Assertion failed) cn == 1`
- As the name suggests, it counts number of pixels within an image having pixel value greater than 0, i.e. pixel values within the range [1 - 255]

#### Example 1:

The following is a binary image:

[image]

```
spot_img = cv2.imread('spots.jpg', 0)
binary_img = cv2.threshold(spot_img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.countNonZero(binary_img)
```

> 5

There are 5 non zero pixels in the image. And given that the image is binary we can conclude there are 5 white pixels (pixel value = 255)

#### Example 2:

[image]

```
code_img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\524316\Desktop\Stack\m1.png', 0)
cv2.countNonZero(code_img)
```

> 5937

In the above gray scale image there are 5937 non zero pixels in the image. And that includes pixel values between [1 - 255]

To get only the count of white pixels [255], use `np.sum()` as mentioned above:

```
np.sum(code_img == 255)
```

> 5792

To get the count of a particular pixel value, use the same as above