# np.sum Not returning total counts

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying this code but it does not return total count for zero[x][y], in this case it should return 5 but all it displays 255 five time.
THIS CODE IS FOR CONNECTED COMPONENTS AND ZERO IS ONE COMPONENT FOR WHITE PIXEL

**Expected Output should be:5**
**But what i am getting is:**
255
255
255
255
255

```
for (x, y) in labels:
        component = uf.find(labels[(x, y)])
        # Update the labels with correct information
        labels[(x, y)] = component
        path='imagesNew/13/'
        if labels[(x, y)]==0:
            Zero[y][x]=int(255)
            Z=Zero[y][x]
            print Z
            if Z==5:
              print Zero[y][x]
              Zeroth = Image.fromarray(Zero)
              Zeroth.save(path+'Zero'+'.png','png')
```

Comment: Please add your expected input and output. At the moment, the question is unclear

Comment: Please include the surrounding code so that we have more context of what is going on.

Comment: You set it to `255` then immediately check if it is `5`... this will never be the case?

Comment: You should be summing the whole image to count. E.g. after you change the pixels to 255, outside the for loop, you just need to `np.sum(Zero)/255`. Or you can just create a counter, `zero_counter` and increment it each time a label pixel is 0.

Comment: I have total 8 if condition for 8 components every condition creates image the above code is creating one image for one component so i want if 5 pixels in one image are found discard now how i edit the above code

Comment: So are you trying to create a mask for each label? `labels == val` will return a boolean mask, you don't need loops here at all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're after. This code will loop through each label in the labeled image, create a boolean mask showing where each label is in the image, and sum that mask to tell you the total count of each label.

```
import numpy as np
labeled_img = np.array([
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 2],
    [1, 0, 0, 2, 2],
    [1, 0, 2, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]])

for label in np.unique(labeled_img):
    print('Quantity of', label, 'labels:', np.sum(labeled_img == label))
```

> Quantity of 0 labels: 5
>   Quantity of 1 labels: 10
>   Quantity of 2 labels: 10

Note that if you used OpenCV to find the connected components, the first return value of `connectedComponents()` is the number of labels, so you can simply loop over `for label in range(n_labels)` instead of `np.unique()`, which would be a tad faster.

Comment: @pixelthread No, I will not code your project for you. However from glossing it over I see that what you're trying to do is simply create a mask for each component and also display the components with colors. This is really simple to do with a few lines of code, so I'll edit to show that. Give me a bit...

Comment: No its not mask its array color part is not related with this

Comment: Either way, @pixelthread the original question you had here was how to get counts of a component and the above code should work fine for this task. If you have a different question, you should open up a new question.

Comment: I can open up but did you understand what i am trying to do

Comment: I am trying to count total number of pixels in image but above code doesn't return total count

Comment: The code I pasted above does exactly that. It returns the total number of pixels for each label.

Comment: Error Too many values to unpack after replacing yours, how do i put it in my code :  for (x, y) in labels:
        component = uf.find(labels[(x, y)])
        # Update the labels with correct information
        labels[(x, y)] = component
        path='imagesNew/13/'
        if labels[(x, y)]==0:
            Zero[y][x]=int(255)
            Z=Zero[y][x]
            print Z
            if Z==5:
              print Zero[y][x]

Comment: @pixelthread I think I see the issue; I was assuming you had the components already. Just simply call `cv2.connectedComponents()` first and then my code will run on that labeled image. You do not need to loop through your image at all.