# Count number of White Pixels per row of an image in Python

Tags: python, opencv, count, pixel

I am stuck trying to count the number of white pixels **per row** in a image.

i have tried this

```
img = cv2.imread("11.jpg") # Its our Image object
mask = np.uint8(np.where(img == 0, 1, 0))
row_counts = cv2.reduce(mask, 1, cv2.REDUCE_SUM, dtype=cv2.CV_32SC1)  # type: ignore
#Data Collection
White_row = 224- row_counts # 224 is max pixels in row
```

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494350/count-total-number-of-white-pixels-in-an-image

Comment: `np.where(img == 0, 1, 0)` -- given that you want to count **white** pixels, why are you looking for **black** ones here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So if i try find the white ones using that value It give a random integer value. Which is why i used that other code from in that link.

Comment: Use np.count_nonzero() and tell it you want to count on the row axis. That will give you an array of counts, one per row. See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html

Answer (score 0):

So i made my own loop algorithm that loops through every pixel and checks the pixel intensity. The image is converted into grey scale.

```
img = Image.open("11.jpg")
img = img.convert("L")  # convert to grayscale
pix = img.load()
width, height = img.size
print(width, height)
print(pix[91,134]) #Tester
White_row = [0] * height
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        if pix[x,y] > 235: # 235 is the threshold
            White_row[y] += 1
Max_Width = np.max(White_row)
Mean_Width = np.mean(White_row)
print ("Max_Width: ", Max_Width)
print ("Mean_Width: ", Mean_Width)
```